# Cannot create new project on Sublime Text 3 [MAVENSMATE]: response from mm: /bin/sh: 1: : Permission denied]

Tags: mavensmate, sublime

I am making my first steps as a Salesforce developer and I am trying to create a new project with MavensMate on Sublime Text 3 and still, I am stuck with this permission issue.
This is the output message from the Sublime Text console.

```
[MAVENSMATE]: OPERATION: new_project
[MAVENSMATE]: {}
[MAVENSMATE]: mm command:   
[MAVENSMATE]: '' -o new_project --ui -c SUBLIME_TEXT_3
[MAVENSMATE]: {}
[MAVENSMATE]: response from mm: /bin/sh: 1: : Permission denied
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 15.04 and I have overriden the MavensMate User settings and set the `"mm_subl_location" : "/usr/local/bin/subl"` i.e a symlink that points to the sublime text installation directory(in my case, i.e `/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text` .

Moreover, I have provided the following permissions for the symlink.

`/usr/local/bin/subl` :
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 may 23 12:59 local/bin/subl -> /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text`

I have also tried to unistall and re-install both Sublime Text 3(build 3083) and MavensMate(v4.0.5), but still, the same problem occurs.

Is this some Unix basic knowledge about file permissions that I am missing here or something else that cannot see?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're probably better off seeking help from the MavensMate developers directly rather than here. Try https://mavensmate.com or https://github.com/joeferraro/mavensmate

Comment: I have posted a similar issue on their page whilst digging in older issues that have been posted there, to see if there's any solution to this.

Comment: After being led in other errors(that I won't dig into details) as well, whilst trying to solve the one forementioned , I finally stumbled upon similar issues on the github page of Mavensmate. The additional errors that I got, seemed to be an issue of Linux 32-bit compatibility with Mavensmate.
I decided to install a 64x OS Linux flavor and I am now able to create a new project.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.